# Saving txt logs into a file creating only once

Tags: android, logcat

I am running into a issue when trying to save the logcat to a file . Below is the code:

```
public void createLogs() {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        
        File appDirectory;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
             appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/myTest");
        }else{
             appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + “/myTest");
        }
        File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/logs");
        
         File logFile = new File(logDirectory, “mytest.txt");

        if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
            appDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        if (!logDirectory.exists()) {
            logDirectory.mkdir();
        }
       
        try {
            //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile + " -r 2048 -n 4");
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

It creates the folder myTest-->logs--->mytest.txt in this folder structure.
It is creating .txt file but when manually delete .txt is not creating again. Please suggest.

Comment: `File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/logs");` Change to: `File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory, "logs");` The other ones too.

Comment: `if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
            if(!appDirectory.mkdir()) return;
        }` The other ones too.

Comment: `but when manually delete .txt is creating again. ` That looks ok to me. Sorry i do not see an issue.

Comment: my bad, manually deleting the .txt , .txt is not creating again

Comment: After doing the above changes, myTest itself is not creating , hence no logs

Comment: You probably do this on an Android 11+ device.

Comment: yes you are right, in Android 10 everything is working fine . Ony in Android 11 ,.txt file gets created only once. And if deleted manually, not creating .txt again though the folders are present

Comment: `but when manually delete .txt ` What is manually?

Comment: Manually means, I am reaching to the folder and explicitly deleting the .txt files from the folder.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11+ devices created files will often be scannd by the MediaStore directly.

But on deleting the file the MediaStore mostly is not informed.

Hence if you try to create a file with the same name again the MediaStore gets involved and wil report that the file already exists.

Remove the MediaStore entry first.

Comment: Thanks for the info, how to delete MediaStore entry , any code sample ?

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore`. Next time you try to dele a file delete it using the MediaStore.